# Footnote citation and bibliography different styles

Tags: biblatex

I am working on my Master’s thesis using the `book` class. I need to write the citations both as footnotes in the text and to collect them at the end in the Bibliography chapter. To do this, I need two different styles, one for the footnote citations and one for the bibliography entries.

I have created the footnote style that I need thanks to the `xpatch` package. However, I do not understand how to change the style of the entries in the bibliography at the end of the thesis (at the moment, the two styles are the same).

For the footnote citations, they have to appear as:

> N. Surname et al., *Title of the paper*. *Title of the journal*, Editor, Year, pages

For the bibliography entries, they have to appear as:

> Surname Name, *Title of the paper*. *Title of the journal*, Editor, Year

This is the MWE (the footnote citation style is correct, the bibliography style is wrong). I compile using XeLaTeX and Biber:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[style=verbose,
doi=false,
firstinits=true,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\pagestyle{plain}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{} 

\addbibresource{Bib.bib}  

 % et al. italics
 \xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{title}{\unspace\addcomma\addspace}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textit{#1}\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textit{#1}\nopunct}  
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textit{#1}\addcomma}  
\renewbibmacro{in:}{ in\nopunct}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\guillemotleft #1\guillemotright \addcomma} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} 

%**BEGIN DOCUMENT**    
\begin{document}

 \chapter{Introduction}
 Lorem ipsum\footcite{Aiello2014}
 Lorem ipsum\footcite{Arksey1999}

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

This is the Bib.bib file

```
%Aiello_Bulgherano
@article{Aiello2014,
  title={{An assessment of the Beerkan method for determining the hydraulic properties of a sandy loam soil}},
  author={Aiello, R and Bagarello, V and Barbagallo, S and Consoli, S and Di Prima, S and Giordano, G and Iovino, M},
  journal={Geoderma},
  volume={235},
  pages={300--307},
  year={2014},
  doi={10.1016/j.geoderma.2014.07.024}
}

%Arksey
@book{Arksey1999,
  title={Interviewing for social scientists: An introductory resource with examples},
  author={Arksey, Hilary and Knight, Peter T},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Sage}
}
```

The footnote citations should look like this (the first is a paper and the second is a book):
[image]

The bibliography citations should look like this (the first is a paper and the second is a book):
[image]

Comment: Is the only difference between citations and the bibliography the name format and number of names or is there more (for example in other entry types)? I'm also a bit confused about the "et al.": Do you want all names in the bibliography and only a certain number of names in the citation (possibly truncated by "et al.")? Or do you want the same number of names in both cases, and simply drop the "et al." in the bibliography (sounds like a bad idea)?

Comment: Completely off-topic: Since you are using XeLaTeX you should drop `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (XeLaTeX is always UTF-8, this one is harmless I think, but it still should be dropped) and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (this chooses different fonts, is probably overridden by `fontspec` later, but I would still remove it as it should basically never be used with Unicode engines).

Comment: Slightly more on-topic again: It is enough to load packages once, so you can drop the second `\usepackage{xpatch}`. You may want to consider loading `csquotes` for proper quotation mark support in `biblatex`, that may allow us to find a more elegant way to say `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\guillemotleft #1\guillemotright \addcomma} `.

Comment: The footnote citation should have the first author and the "et al." (e.g. A. Smith et al.), whereas the bibliography should have listed all the authors with full names and surnames. There is this difference not only with papers but also with books (this is why I put a paper and a book in the .bib example). Thank you also for the other suggestions

Comment: OK. One more thing: You say "Name Surname" in the bibliography, does that mean you want "Anne Uthor" and not say, "Uthor, Anne"? That would be a bit unusual, since the bibliography is sorted by (family) names and that would mean that the first letter in a bibliography entry is not necessarily the letter that determines the sort order.

Comment: It may help if you could add the expected output of the minimal example to your question. Then there is less guessing about what "Name Surname" means.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately the guidelines I have to follow have a wrong example. The bibliography has to be "Uthor Anne" without comma. I modified the question.

Comment: Ok, I will add a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks. "Uthor Anne" without a comma and without additional markup of the family name is a bit unusual. I noticed the guillemets in the journal name: Is this a French style? (In French family names are often set in small caps, which would make it easier to navigate "Uᴛʜᴏʀ Anne".)

Comment: I added the example. I know this is a bit unusual, this is why I find it tricky to find a solution... Anyhow, I added a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I noticed that you set `maxbibnames=99,` to get all names in the bibliography, but the screenshot of the desired output shows only the truncated list in the bibliography "Aiello Robert *et al.*". (I'm also curious how the example knows the given name of Aiello is Robert given that on the paper it only says "R. Aiello")

Comment: Also: Where does the ", 6." at the end in the bibliography come from?

Comment: It knows the name because I wanted to show how I would like it to appear (in other words, it has not been created as a real bibliography entry, but as text that shows how I need the entries to be shown). With respect to `maxbibnames`, it comes from another example I found online, it worked so I did not modify that.

Comment: Ah, I see: Do you want all authors in the bibliography or not?

Comment: If it is a paper, it has to be "Uthor Anne et al., ...". Whereas, if it is a book, it should have all authors "Uthor Anne and Smith Mark"

Comment: WHAT? I have never seen that before. Are you sure that is the rule? Does it not have to do with the number of authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still a few aspects of the style that are a bit unclear to me, but I guess the following should get you pretty far already.

As I read the question it is mainly about the name format. The name format you need to change is called `sortname`. In the citation we need a format that gives us given name inital and family name (the new format `g-family`).

`cite:full` is just a copy of the `cite:full` from [`verbose.cbx`, ll. 93-99,](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose.cbx#L93-L99) with the name format changed.

In the bibliography we want the "family given" name order and no comma between the parts (that is controlled by `\revsdnamepunct`).

I slightly rewrote your method to put commas between the elements of the reference: It is slightly easier and cleaner with `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose,
  maxbibnames=999,
  doi=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{g-family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{g-family}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\guillemotleft #1\guillemotright}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Aiello2014,
  title   = {An assessment of the Beerkan method for determining
             the hydraulic properties of a sandy loam soil},
  author  = {Aiello, R. and Bagarello, V. and Barbagallo, S. and Consoli, S.
             and Di Prima, S. and Giordano, G. and Iovino, M.},
  journal = {Geoderma},
  volume  = {235},
  pages   = {300--307},
  year    = {2014},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.geoderma.2014.07.024}
}
@book{Arksey1999,
  title     = {Interviewing for social scientists: An introductory resource with examples},
  author    = {Arksey, Hilary and Knight, Peter T.},
  year      = {1999},
  publisher = {Sage}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum\footcite{Aiello2014}
  ipsum\footcite{Arksey1999}
  dolor\footcite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "R. Aiello et al., An assessment of the Beerkan method for determining the hydraulic properties of a sandy loam soil, in «Geoderma» 235 (2014), 300–307." in citations//"Aiello R., Bagarello V., Barbagallo S., Consoli S., Di Prima S., Giordano G., and Iovino M., An assessment of the Beerkan method for determining the hydraulic properties of a sandy loam soil, in «Geoderma» 235 (2014), 300–307" in bibliography]